# Python regex split woes

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to split up a string into a list.  It almost works, but for some reason it produces an extra blank list element at the beginning and end.

```
line = "A12B1234123456  Misc text"
re.split('^([A-H])(\d{2})?([A-Z])?(\d{4})?(\d{6})?\t(.*)$', line)
['', 'A', '12', 'B', '1234', '123456', 'Misc text', '']
```

I was expecting `['A', '12', 'B', '1234', '123456', 'Misc text']`
Why would this happen, and how can I prevent it?

Comment: What's your expected output? and how you want to split your string?

Comment: Is that string separated with multiple spaces?

Comment: Can't produce the same output as you are telling.

Comment: For some reason, SO renders my tab within the string as spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using split, basically, and it separates the string in parts, using your regex as separator.

I think that what you are looking for is to **match** selected groups in the regular expression:

```
line = "A12B1234123456\tMisc text"
m = re.match('^([A-H])(\d{2})?([A-Z])?(\d{4})?(\d{6})?\t(.*)$', line)
m.groups()
>>> ('A', '12', 'B', '1234', '123456', 'Misc text')
```

This is the list, I think, you are expecting.

Comment: If you don't want to match from the start of the string (this is not the case), you must use **re.search** instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is correct but don't use `re.split` for printing your matches.

Use `re.findall` to print all matches (captured groups):

```
>>> print re.findall(r'([A-H])(\d{2})?([A-Z])?(\d{4})?(\d{6})?\t(.*)$', line)[0]
('A', '12', 'B', '1234', '123456', 'Misc text')
```

Comment: Curious this would returns a list of tuples.  I know it can be converted to a list easily enough, but it seems like a very strange thing to do.

Comment: Sorry you mean using `findall` or `match` instead of `split` is strange?